# Почему не работает View.OnClickListener в моем View?

Tags: java, android

Делаю свой View, но почему то не работает OnClickListener Вроде должен работать или что то упустил.

```
 public class TableEditText extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText implements View.OnClickListener {
    
            Paint paint;
    
            public TableEditText(Context context) {
                super(context);
                setCursorVisible(false);
                setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                setKeyListener(null);
                setOnClickListener(this);
            }
    
            public TableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
                paint = new Paint();
                /*paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);*/
                setCursorVisible(false);
                setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                setKeyListener(null);
                setOnClickListener(this);
            }
    
            public TableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
            }
    
    
            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);
                super.onDraw(canvas);
    
            }
    
            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                L.i("TOUCH EVENT");
                int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
    
                switch (action) {
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                        L.i("Action was DOWN");
                        return true;
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
                        L.i("Action was MOVE");
                        return true;
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
                        L.i("Action was UP");
                        return true;
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL):
                        L.i("Action was CANCEL");
                        return true;
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE):
                        L.i("Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                                "of current screen element");
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
            }
           
    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                L.i("CLICK");
            }
    
    
        }
```

Comment: Уберите onTouchEvent должен заработать.

Comment: Да я тоже про это подумал, что возможно он мешает, спасибо

Comment: Да мешал он, теперь работает но только 2 раза кликнуть если, я так понимаю что View фокусируется. А так чтобы просто кликнуть и вызывался такого нельзя сделать.

Comment: А зачем вы вешаете `setOnClickListener(this);` на себя же? Там где-то и ищите источник проблемы.